# Update DRCSIM setup.sh

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It would be nice to include

```
 
export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/drcsim-1.3/models:$GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH
```

in drcsim-1.x/setup.sh

Currently to access the Atlas meshes we do something like:
file://../models/atlas/meshes/ltorso.dae

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/558/update-drcsim-setup.sh/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2012-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[Ticketed](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/77/add-models-directory-to).

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2012-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0